# Book suggestions for a concise introduction to computational linguistics?

Tags: computational-linguistics, textbooks

I am fairly new to the field of linguistics and am looking for a book as a fairly concise basic introduction to computational linguistics (I already have some computer science background). What is a good book to read in this area for a general introduction to the field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Markus Dickinson, Chris Brew & Detmar Meurers (2013), *Language and Computers*, should be what you're looking for.

A rather more extensive classic for a second textbook is Daniel Jurafsky & James H. Martin (2014), *Speech and Language Processing*.

If you want something more hands-on you could also work through the guide to an NLP toolkit, for beginners specifically [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/book/) comes to mind.